# Connect and pass data between two Cordova Apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap

I am new to Cordova programming and I was wondering if it is possible to connect two apps on different devices. For instance I enter a string in a text box on one device and other device somehow receives it and can alert it. Is this possible?